# Make calculations in SQL query for selecting records with a rating

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My Data is set out like this:

```
-------------------------------
|id|name|vote_count|vote_score|
|1 |Jim |9         |14        |
|2 |Bert|8         |17        |
|3 |Bob |43        |45        |
|4 |Will|1         |5         |
-------------------------------
```

You can work out a users score by doing this:

```
$score = round($result['vote_score'] / $result['vote_count'], 2);
```

Is there an SQL query I can do to only get users with a score of 3 or more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean:

```
select * from users where round(vote_score / vote_count, 2) >= 3;
```

?

Comment: Exactly, I didn't know you could do that :)

Answer (score 3):

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE ROUND((vote_score / vote_count),2) >= 3`

Answer (score 1):

How about -

```
SELECT
  id,
  name,
  vote_count, 
  vote_score, 
  vote_score / vote_count as score
FROM 
  tablename
WHERE
  vote_score / vote_count >= 3;
```